# PassportJS Verify Callback done(xx, xx...), is it already declared or I need to declare myself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm new to JS and new to node. This seems a stupid question since I have not found others have the same question as I do. Anyway, my goal is to understand it and use the tool.

I'm trying to use PassportJS. However, when I look at the guide and source code. I'm not able to find how the Verify Callback: done is defined. There is an intro for [Verify Callback](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) and some comments in the source code like [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/blob/master/lib/exchange/password.js):

> Callbacks:
>
> This middleware requires an `issue` callback, for which the function 
>   signature is as follows:
>
> ```
> function(client, username, password, scope, done) { ... }
> ```
>
> `client` is the authenticated client instance attempting to obtain an
>   access  token.  `username` and `password` and the resource owner's
>   credentials.  `scope` is the scope of access requested by the client. 
>   `done` is called to  issue an access token:
>
> ```
>  done(err, accessToken, refreshToken, params)
> ```
>
> `accessToken` is the access token that will be sent to the client. 
>   An  optional `refreshToken` will be sent to the client, if the server
>   chooses to  implement support for this functionality.  Any additional
>   `params` will be  included in the response.  If an error occurs,
>   `done` should be invoked with  `err` set in idomatic Node.js fashion.

Do I need to declare done myself? Like function(client, username, password, scope, function done(xx,xx...) {...}) { ... }

Or it is already declared? In this case, what does done return? Where can I find its declaration?

I guess I have not fully caught some ideas in async JS which leads to my current understanding challenge.

Thanks in advance,

Liwei

EDIT 1:

done(xx, xx...) { This is the part I'm looking for, my current guess is I need to write this myself, since I couldn't find this part in source code }

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're trying to implement whats called local strategy (vs social one), see an example of usage at: http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and thanks for your link. Just lost my reply by closing the tab accidently. I'm trying to implement bearer token with oauth2orize, which is not that important for my question since Passport uses verify callback as a standard way. I updated my question to try to make it clearer.